# (C) How do I use dynamic memory for character input? And how do I organize the values inputed in a certain way?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, counter, dynamic-memory-allocation

These are the directions:

Read characters from standard input until EOF (the end-of-file mark) is read. Do not prompt the user to enter text - just read data as soon as the program starts.
Keep a running count of each different character encountered in the input, and keep count of the total number of characters input (excluding EOF).

I know I have to store the values in an array somehow using the malloc() function. I have to organize each character entered by keeping count of how many times that particular character was entered.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, since you are reading from standard input, there are at most 256 different possibilities.  (You read in a char).  Since that's the case, you could just statically allocate 256 integers for counting. `int charCount[256];`  Just initialize each value to 0, then increment each time a match is input.

Alternatively, if you must have malloc, then:

```
// This code isn't exactly what I'd turn in for homework - just a starting
// point, and non-tested besides.
int* charCount = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 256); // Allocate 256.
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) charCount[i] = 0; // Initialize to 0.

// Counting and character input go here, in a loop.
int inputChar;

// Read in inputChar with a call to getChar(). Then:
charCount[inputChar]++; // Increment user's input value.

// Provide your output.

free(charCount); // Release your memory.
```

Comment: Hmm, you can enter the same character in as many times as you want though. That is the purpose of the counter.

Comment: Well, the int gives you a limit of 2 BILLION times for each character.  That should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int count[256] = {0};
    char *l, *lp;

    while (scanf(" %ms", &l) != EOF) {
        for (lp = l; *lp; lp++)
            count[(int)*lp]++;
        free(l);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (isprint(i) && count[i])
            printf("%c: %d\n", i, count[i]);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

Compile:

```
c99 t.c
```

Run:

```
$ ./a.out 
abc
ijk
abc
<-- Ctrl-D (Unix-like) or Ctrl-Z (Windows) for EOF
a: 2
b: 2
c: 2
i: 1
j: 1
k: 1
```